# Silverlight: How to create checkboxes inside GroupBox dynamically from collections of collections?

Tags: silverlight, checkbox, groupbox

My case is like, I have a collection object that contain a collection as:

```
public class GroupBoxColletion
{
    public string GroupBoxName;
    public list<CheckBox> CheckBoxName;
}
```

Note: I have total 5 GroupBoxes and in each groupbox I need to create 100 check-boxes.

How can I create this using binding technique in silverlight 4.0?

Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do but I'm not sure this is the right way to achieve it. If you want to use DataBinding in Silverlight, then you should have data to bind. Unfortunately a CheckBox in itself isn't a piece of data but a usercontrol. I would suggest to create a data collection that you could bind to the CheckBoxes.

```
public class GroupBoxCollection
{
    public string GroupBoxName;
    public List<bool> CheckBoxName;
}
```

This way you could bind the values of the CheckBoxName collection to an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate that contains a CheckBox.

I hope this helps a bit. If you need more info, just write a comment and I'll edit this answer with more help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate your concerns here.

---

Your model will have a structure like this:

```
public class GroupBoxCollection
{
    public List<GroupBoxContent> Collections { get; set; }
}

public class GroupBoxContent
{
    public string GroupBoxName { get; set; }
    public List<GroupBoxItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class GroupBoxItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

And your XAML will look something like this. I'm not using GroupBoxes here because SL4 does not have them by default. I'll use a Grid instead, but you can modify the code to use them yourself :)

```
    <ListBox x:Name="TestListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5" Background="Azure">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupBoxName}" />
                    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding ItemName}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And in it's code-behind, you can do something like:

```
TestListBox.DataContext = [an instance of GroupBoxCollection here];
```

---

Of course, you can pretty this up by styling/templating things the way you want to, and possibly using something other than ListBoxes, but that's the overall idea.

**Note:**

You may also need to make your model implement INotifyPropertyChanged and/or use ObservableCollection instead of List depending on your needs. You may also need to use TwoWay databinding if you want your view to modify your model when the user checks/unchecks any of the checkboxes.

If you want to test my sample **as is** to see what happens, make sure you populate your instance of GroupBoxCollection (that you set as the DataContext of TestListBox) **before** you set it as the DataContext.